# represent vector as a sum of two

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have to represent vector $\mathbf{g}$ as a sum of $\mathbf{g}_1+\mathbf{g}_2$
where $\mathbf{g}_1 \in L$ and $\mathbf{g}_2 \in L^{\bot}$

if $L=\langle \mathbf{a}_1,\mathbf{a}_2,\mathbf{a}_3 \rangle$

and $\mathbf{a}_1=(1,-1,1,-1) \quad  \mathbf{a}_2=(0,1,-1,1) \quad \mathbf{a}_3=(2,1,-5,1) \quad \mathbf{g}=(3,-1,-1,2)$

I really do not know how to approach it, I did not find examples, can someone explain me basic logic with steps, I will try the rest of work myself

Comment: Hint: For this problem, I think the least amount of work will be to compute a basis for $L^\perp$, which will consist of a single vector, and then computing the projection of $\mathbf g$ onto this vector.

Answer (score 0):

**just a hint**

$$g=g_1+g_2$$
$$=ua_1+va_2+wa_3+g_2$$

$$g.a_j=ua_1.a_j+va_2.a_j+wa_3.a_j$$

with $j=1,2,3$, we get the components $u,v,w $ by solving a linear system .

Comment: what would be $v$ and $w$ ?